# NetCDF shared library gives SIGFPE using -auto -openmp

Tags: fortran, openmp, fortran90, netcdf, intel-fortran

I have a large `Fortran-90` serial code (so I preferably need a general approach to my question rather then multiple specific changes of the code) which I would like to parallel using clauses of `OpenMP`. I would like to try the coarse-grain parallelization, since the main body of my code looks like :

```
Program Example 

  Serial code here

  DO I=is,ie
     DO J=js,je
        Main body of calculations
    ENDDO
  ENDDO

  Serial code here

End Program Example
```

(1) What are the preferred steps of preparing your serial code for parallelization ?
 (2) Since `-openmp` sets `automatic` as default (from the compiler manual), it moves local scalars and arrays to the stack. I have tried first using the `-auto`  for running the code (the compiler flags are : `'ifort -g -O3 -mcmodel=medium -xHost -auto -no-prec-div -fpconstant -fp-model precise -fpe0 -traceback -ftrapuv -convert big_endian -gen-interfaces -warn interfaces -I/usr/local/netcdf/4.3.3.1/include -L/usr/local/netcdf/4.3.3.1/lib -lnetcdff -lnetcdf'`) and got a `SIGFPE` : `Program received signal SIGFPE, Arithmetic exception.
0x00002aaaab445885 in pow.L () from /usr/local/netcdf/4.3.3.1/lib/libnetcdf.so.7`
(3) I have tried also `-openmp` (without any clauses in the serial code!) and it `SIGFPE` at the same point.

Any insights/thoughts of how to use compiler flags wisely (and probably modify slightly my code) would be be greatly appreciate.

Comment: It would be better to put questions (2) and (3) in a separate post and make the current one all about question (1) me thinks.

Comment: From this snippet we can't say anything. If you want to help to solve that error, we need to know what is happening in that loop and which parts of memory it accesses. Generally, OpenMP is not the best tool for very coarse grain parallelism, MPI is better suited to that in my opinion.

Comment: @moarningsun - appreciate your thought but I see very clear relation between the three semi-questions.  Vladimir F - thanks for the note. The specific error does not relate to my fortran code which I want to parallelise, but to the way the netcdf shared library behaves under the '-auto' flag option. I will obviously need multiple synchronization clauses in the corased-approach, but my question is referring now to how the serial code would be identically calculated when compile and link using -openmp flag option.

Comment: In the past, I was quite successful with `gfortran`'s flag `-ffpe-trap=...`. Actually, LAPACK has some routines which rely on floating point exceptions for improved performance (e.g. `?syevr`).

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, it's very difficult to help with a specific SIGFPE error in your code, especially from the information given. SIGFPE  suggests an arithmetic error which may be completely unrelated to the multithreading. I would suggest checking the line it occurs and look for divide by zero, etc. You could also just remove the -fpe0 flag to avoid this error (not recommended). For openMP, the simplest example of running multiple thread in the form you have,

```
Program Example 
implicit none

    integer   :: I, J
    integer   :: is, ie, js, je
    integer   :: nthreads, OMP_GET_NUM_THREADS
    integer   :: ithread, omp_get_thread_num

    !Serial code here

!$OMP PARALLEL 

    nthreads = OMP_GET_NUM_THREADS()
    ithread  = omp_get_thread_num()
    is = 1; ie = 10
    js = 1; je = 5

    DO I=is,ie
     DO J=js,je
        !Main body of calculations
        print'(4(a,i5))', 'loop I= ', I, & 
                              ' J= ', J, &
                        ' on thread ', ithread+1, &
                        ' of ', nthreads
    ENDDO
    ENDDO

!$OMP END PARALLEL

    !Serial code here

end program
```

Which can be compiled using ifort -openmp script.f90. Hope this helps.

Comment: @ Ed Smith -Thanks; you guys seem to miss my point here (this is my fault) : my point was to get some clues why the '-auto' flag causes this SIGFPE in the NetCDF shared library, and in general how the '-auto' effects can be overcome. The next step is combining the '-openmp' flag (which I tried). NOTE: no parallelization included in my code, For now I just want to make sure the '-openmp' flag gives the same results as without the flag (and currently it does not produce the expected results). Thank for the general structure of the coarse-grain parallelization.

Comment: Hmm, okay, may be best to change title to NetCFD with auto flags so someone with experience can help? Maybe even remove the openmp from the question and ask a new once the SIGFPE is fixed?

Comment: Agree, especially the title says something completely different.

Comment: Guys, appreciate your points, but these are essential points to users which his/her very long code (>10k lines) can not be transferred automatically to include OpenMP clauses  by simply include as a first step the -openmp flag and maintain the same results (I'll update the title to include shared NetCDF library).